# XML XSLT %0A%09%09 ? fix?

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt

I'm getting weird characters being appended to the front of my hash (#) "%0A%09%09#2", I'm using Eclipse and java processor Xalan 2.7.1

```
    <xsl:for-each select="fps-photo-atlas/portion">
<a>
<xsl:attribute name="href" >
    #<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(food-number)" />
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="food-description" />
</a>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Preferred output is...

```
 <body><a href="#1">Rice </a></body>
```

Actual output is..

```
 <body><a href="%0A%09%09#1">Rice </a></body>
```

Fixed it Solution (thanks Ign)

```
<xsl:attribute name="href" >#<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(food-number)" /></xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: Did you try getting rid of the whitespace, specifically the newline and the two tabs?

Comment: You have two good answers, please be sure to upvote both and then "accept" whichever one you think best answers the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A text node in the stylesheet has it's [whitespace stripped](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip) unless one of the following apply:

- it is directly inside an 'xsl:text' element
- it contains a non-whitespace character
- it is retained by use of 'xml:space' attributes

The unwanted whitespace is in the same text node as your # character, and is therefore preserved.

There are several ways to exclude the unwanted whitespace.

Use an [Attribute Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) instead of 'xsl:attribute'.

```
<a href="#{normalize-space(food-number)}">
    <xsl:value-of select="food-description" />
</a>
```

Move the # character into an 'xsl:text' element.

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href" >
        <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(food-number)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="food-description" />
</a>
```

Move the # character into the 'value-of' expression.

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href" >
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('#',normalize-space(food-number))" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="food-description" />
</a>
```

Remove the whitespace from the stylesheet.

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href" >#<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(food-number)></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="food-description" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks lachlan lots of options :)